# Change Keys for Users

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm currently working with a website which is being developed in ASP.NET and C#. I'm using EF6 and need to change the default tables to my own custom tables. I have managed to do that with a problem. In my custom table the `UserId` is an `int` rather than default `nvarchar(128)`. I am following this **[demo](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity#userclass)** but I keep getting an error at the first line.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomLogin>
{
}
```

The error is: "**The non-generic type Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser**" cannot be used with type arguments.

I did some research and came across this **[post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1976681.aspx?The%20non%20generic%20type%20Microsoft%20AspNet%20Identity%20IUser%20cannot%20be%20used%20with%20type%20arguments)**. I have updated all the core libraries but the error still exists. Has anyone else faced this problem before or am I the lucky one? Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two IdentityUser classes that come with ASP.NET. One is declared as:

```
public class IdentityUser : IdentityUser<string, 
        IdentityUserLogin, 
        IdentityUserRole, 
        IdentityUserClaim>, IUser
```

and the other is:

```
public class IdentityUser<TKey, TLogin, TRole, TClaim> : IUser<TKey>
        where TLogin : IdentityUserLogin<TKey>
        where TRole : IdentityUserRole<TKey>
        where TClaim : IdentityUserClaim<TKey>
```

You will be declaring a subtype of the generically-typed class and will need all four generic types in the declaration. And you'll also need classes that inherit `IdentityUserRole<int>`, `IdentityUserClaim<int>`, along with your `CustomLogin` class, which I assume is a derivative of `IdentityUserLogin<int>`.

Folling your naming convention, you should declare your class as

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomLogin, CustomRole, CustomClaim>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and in depth information. I've tried what you suggested but seem to be getting the exact same error message :/